Do I need to tend spring bulbs after I plant them in the fall?
I impulse purchased a bag of miscellaneous spring bulbs at Aldi of all places and planted them along a driveway. I am in the Midwest USA gardening zone 6b, approximately 40 inches of precipitation every year.
I planted the bulbs to the depth and spacing the package recommended, mulched lightly and watered them in.
Do they need anything else from me in between now and when they emerge?

As they say, it depends...  Do you have squirrels in the area?  They are hungry right now and will dig up bulbs and eat them.  You can put chicken wire or flat stones over till the ground has hardened.
I highly recommend planting deeper than the recommendations to make it harder for squirrels.
If you have snow or rain over the winter that is all the bulbs need to settle in.
The next possibility is in the spring when hungry rabbits, chipmunks and squirrels will eat flowers.  You can't stop them but you can plant types which are not tasty to them like daffodils, allium and fritillaria.

Hmm... I do have squirrels, rabbits, and chipmunks all over the place, though they usually get enough from my yard to leave the front garden alone. I'll keep an eye on them. So far the only damage is from a neighborhood game of tag that moved through the garden.

I have one book which claims (I can't confirm, I haven't done the experiment) that planting deeply reduces the rate of increase (bulbs making new bulbs) - written by the sort of person who evidently thinks increase is a bad thing (oh, the horror of having the initial design change!) Certainly the overcrowded ones tend to be shallow, but I think they get that way by pushing up as they multiply, so unclear that planting shallow would get them there faster. Anyway, squirrels tend to keep me planting mostly daffodils, though sometimes "protective garlic co-planting" seems to help.
